# how to find MAX value on columns generated by SUM

Tags: mysql, sql, database

this is my data

```
+---------+-------------+
| playerName | score    |
+---------+-------------+
| Player1    | 1        |
| Player2    | 1        |
| Player3    | 1        |
| Player1    | 0        |
| Player2    | 1        |
| Player3    | 1        |
| Player1    | 1        |
| Player2    | 0        |
| Player3    | 1        |
| Player3    | 1        |
+---------+-------------+
```

but when I used this query:

```
SELECT tt.playerName, MAX(sumS) AS max2 FROM table1 tt INNER JOIN (SELECT playerName,Sum(score) AS sumS FROM table1 GROUP BY playerName) T2 ON tt.playerName= t2.playerName
```

I got :

```
+---------+-------------+
|playerName| score      |
+---------+-------------+
| Player1  | 4          |
+---------+-------------+
```

> but I'm looking for this result:

```
+---------+-------------+
|playerName| score      |
+---------+-------------+
| Player3  | 4          |
+---------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT playerName, Sum(score) AS sumS
FROM table1
GROUP BY playerName
ORDER BY sumS DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

In the case of ties, this will return only one of the rows.  If you want all of them, then one method is:

```
SELECT playerName, Sum(score) AS sumS
FROM table1 t1
GROUP BY playerName
HAVING sumS = (SELECT Sum(tt1.score)
               FROM table1 tt1
               WHERE tt1.playerName = t1.playerName
               ORDER BY sumS DESC
               LIMIT 1
              );
```

Comment: but what will happen if there two players have same score ?

Comment: In case of same score, We should also use playerName field in order by clause as well.